# Pandas function to.csv write only boolean values but not the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I´m trying to print my filtered DataFrame in a new file using the function
`to.csv` with Pandas.
This is part of my code:

```
df_1_S = pd.read_csv("S_YN00.csv",sep="\t", names=['ID1',"ID2","dN","dS","t","Label_ID1","Label_ID2","Group"])

S_greather_than = (df_1_S["dN"] < 6) & (df_1_S["dS"] < 6) & (df_1_S["t"] < 6)

df_1_S.loc[S_greather_than]
```

The previous part of the code print the following filtered DF (with values only <= 6):

```
              ID1          ID2      dN  ...   Label_ID1   Label_ID2   Group
0       QJY77946    NP_073551   0.0241  ...   229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
1       QJY77954    NP_073551   0.0119  ...   229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
2       QJY77954     QJY77946   0.0119  ...   229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
3       QJY77962    NP_073551   0.0119  ...   229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
4       QJY77962     QJY77946   0.0119  ...   229E-CoV    229E-CoV    Intra
          ...          ...     ...  ...         ...         ...     ...
252946  QKV43781     QKV43751   0.0118  ...   PEDV-CoV    PEDV-CoV    Intra
252947  QKV43781     QKV43757   0.0118  ...   PEDV-CoV    PEDV-CoV    Intra
252948  QKV43781     QKV43763   0.0059  ...   PEDV-CoV    PEDV-CoV    Intra
252949  QKV43781     QKV43769   0.0059  ...   PEDV-CoV    PEDV-CoV    Intra
252950  QKV43781     QKV43775  -0.0000  ...   PEDV-CoV    PEDV-CoV    Intra
```

All fine with that, however when I try to print this in a new file with this line:

```
S_greather_than.to_csv("C:/Filter_S_YN00.tsv")
```

Print only boolean values in the new file:

```
0,True
1,True
2,True
3,True
4,True
5,True
6,True
7,False
8,True
9,True
10,True
```

How can fix that? I want to print the new DF, with the filtered values.
Any idea or help is welcome
Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your command

```
S_greather_than.to_csv("C:/Filter_S_YN00.tsv")
```

use

```
df_1_S.loc[S_greather_than].to_csv("C:/Filter_S_YN00.tsv")
```

---

*The explanation:*

You wrote to `.tsv` only your filter, not the dataframe filteret by it.

Comment: Thank you for your help Marian! This works perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)